# How can I convert text color values from text file to Color?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
StreamReader w = new StreamReader(@"d:\colors.txt");
w.ReadLine();
w.Close();
```

Example of the text file line content

RGBA(0.272, 0.272, 0.272, 0.500)

I want to convert the values to Color
So I will be able to do later for example :

```
Color c = colorFromTextFile;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried to extract values `R`, `G`, `B`, `A` from strings like this `RGBA(0.272, 0.272, 0.272, 0.500)`, and then use a method [`Color.FromArgb`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb?view=netcore-3.1#System_Drawing_Color_FromArgb_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_) to convert values `R`, `G`, `B`, `A` to `Color`?

Comment: @IliarTurdushev I guess OP uses [`UnityEngine.Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-ctor.html) which uses `float` values but yes the principle would be the same ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string looks like given

```
RGBA(0.272, 0.272, 0.272, 0.500)
```

You could use

1. [`string.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof) to find the `(` and `)`
2. [`string.Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.substring#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) to then extract the string between those two
3. [`string.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.split) to finally cut it into the individual color components
4. [`Single.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.single.parse) to parse the given string into `float` values
5. Pass these to the [`Color` constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-ctor.html)

Something like e.g.

```
public static bool TryParse(string input, out Color color)
{
    // e.g. input = "RGBA(0.272, 0.272, 0.272, 0.500)"

    color = default;

    try
    {
        var firstChar = input.IndexOf('(') + 1; 
        // = 5

        var lastChar = input.IndexOf(')') - 1; 
        // = 31

        var colorDataLength = lastChar - firstCharIndex; 
        // 26

        var colorData = input.SubString(firstChar, colorDataLength); 
        // = "0.272, 0.272, 0.272, 0.500"

        var colorParts = colorData.Split(','); 
        // = string[]{"0.272", " 0.272", " 0.272", " 0.500"}

        var r = float.Parse(colorParts[0].Trim());
        // = 0.272f

        var g = float.Parse(colorParts[1].Trim());
        // = 0.272f

        var b = float.Parse(colorParts[2].Trim());
        // = 0.272f

        var a = float.Parse(colorParts[3].Trim());
        // = 0.5f

        color = new Color(r, g, b, a);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"{e.GetType()} while trying to parse string \"{input}\"!\n{e.Message}\n{e.StackTrace}");
        return false;
    }  
}
```

So you could use it like e.g.

```
if(TryParse("RGBA(0.272, 0.272, 0.272, 0.500)", out var color))
{
    // success -> use color
    someMaterial.color = color;
}
```

---

Alternatively as [TheGeneral mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62422308/how-can-i-convert-text-color-values-from-text-file-to-color/62422459?noredirect=1#comment110399199_62422459) in the comments you could also shorten this a bit and use [`Regex.Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches) to directly find the individual color components. Like

```
var colorParts = Regex.Matches(input, @"[0-9](\.[0-9]+)");
// = MatchCollection{"0.272", "0.272", "0.272", "0.500"}
```

In this case you wouldn't need to use `string.Trim()` as these are already without the spaces.

And yes you can also use [Linq `Select`](https://learn.microsoft.comdotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) in order to do the `float.Parse` on all elements in one go like

```
// This is basically a shortcut for doing something like
//var colorComponentsList = new List<float>();
//foreach(var part in colorParts)
//{
//    colorComponentsList.Add(float.Parse(part.Value));
//}
//var colorComponents = colorComponentsList.ToArray();
var colorComponents = colorParts.Select(part => float.Parse(part.Value)).ToArray();
// = float[]{0.272f, 0.272f, 0.272f, 0.5f}

color = new Color(colorComponents[0], colorComponents[1], colorComponents[2], colorComponents[3]);
```

---

If you are, however, not bound to the file format you should rather store your colors in HTML color format (Hexadecimal)

```
#45454580
```

and use [`ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString.html)

---

*Note typed on smartphone so please be patient but I hope the idea gets clear :)*

Comment: You could regex them out i guess `Regex.Matches(input, @"[0-9](\.[0-9]+)").Select(x => double.Parse(x.Value)).ToArray()`